# Webpack import not transpiling Babel code

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I am using React and Webpack and weirdly when I import a class containing a React component the transpilation doesn't seem to happen and i get:

```
function class Test extends _react2.default.Component {
        constructor() {
            return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, Object.getPrototypeOf(Test).apply(this, arguments));
        }
```

etc.

However when I define the class inline this does not happen.

Main required webpack file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

// Components
import SignUp from './components/test';

// Styles
import './styles/sass/materialize.scss';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/sign-up" component={SignUp} />
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('react-hook')
);
```

Webpack Config:

```
import path from "path";
import webpack from 'webpack';

export default {
    entry: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/main.js')
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|lib)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react','es2015']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.s?css$/,
                loader: 'style!css!sass'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|eot|svg)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            jQuery: "jquery"
        })
    ]
};
```

Comment: Please include the test source.

Comment: Did you defined `.babelrc` presets  ?

Answer (score 1):

This issue was fixed by reinstalling all node_modules.

Comment: wow, thanks for this comment! there was no hint I could find.
I reinstalled `npm` package and it  just worked fine.